# Import a .sql file

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

How to import a .sql file for a database using the command prompt? I don't know how to use the address of my file in command prompt

Comment: This is an English language site. Please post in English, or ask your question at [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) instead. Good luck.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com (aproveite e aprenda a usar também as keywords da linguagem humana: "por favor", "obrigado", "com licença" etc... cabaço :)

Comment: Your question is a bit thin even when translated into English.

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server - do not randomly pick tags that do not apply to your actual situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this command

```
mysql -u<username> -p<password> <databasename> < path_to_your_file.sql
```

Replace "username","password","databasename" by your info